# How to use a custom property of another object in an open graph object?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Sorry I am very new to open graph and have been having difficulty to post an action the way I want it to be...

If I have two custom objects (book and author) and an action (read) that connects with "book". I also added in the "book" object a custom property of the type "author".

Q1) How do I get the "read" action post to include a link to the "author" object? Is that even possible? So far I do not see where I can use the custom property of type "author" anywhere.

Q2) If the custom property name is "myapp:author", in the meta tag what exactly should I put in the content?? as in `<meta property="myapp:author" content="??????">`

please if anyone can shed some light I would greatly appreciate it. I can't seem to find any fb documentation or stackoverflow post describing how exactly to use custom property and i have been trying to figure this out for two days...

---

This [documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/bestpractices/tips-open-graph/) describe what I can do, but exactly how do I do it???

"Using the same cooking app example, if we wanted to add the author to the recipe object, we could simply add a property “author” to the object where we would provide the author’s name as a string. Another way to model this would be to have the “author” property point to a “profile” object that has meta data on the author’s first name, last name, profile picture etc."

so back to my two questions

Q1) If I have a "cook" "recipe" action post, in the post can I have a reference to "author" (e.g. User cooked a recipe by author on myapp)

Q2) What should be in the content of the meta tag for the "author" property???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [Bultin Object Book](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/#book) to understand how to define custom properties

```
<html>
    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# 
                  book: http://ogp.me/ns/book#">
     <meta property="fb:app_id"               content="YOUR_APP_ID"> 
     <meta property="og:type"                 content="book"> 
     <meta property="og:url"                  content="URL of this object">
     <meta property="og:image"                content="URL to an image">
     <meta property="og:description"          content="Description of content">
     <meta property="og:title"                content="Name of book">
     <meta property="book:release_date"       content="DateTime">
     <meta property="book:author"             content="Who wrote this">
     <meta property="book:isbn"               content="ISBN Number">
     <meta property="book:tag"                content="keywords">
    </head>
<body>
    <!--a wonderful book -->
</body>
</html>
```

For Custom types, like referring / using an an object in another object, See this [complex object type](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/complextypes/)

```
<html>
  <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# 
       your-og-app: http://ogp.me/ns/apps/your-og-app#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id"                    content="YOUR_APP_ID"> 
  <meta property="og:type"                      content="your-og-app:restaurant"> 
  <meta property="og:title"                     content="Sample Restaurant"> 
  <meta property="og:description"               content="A great sample restaurant"> 
  <meta property="og:image"                     content="https://your-great-image"> 
  <meta property="your-og-app:owner:street_address" 
        content="1601 S. California St."> 
  <meta property="your-og-app:owner:locality"       content="Palo Alto"> 
  <meta property="your-og-app:owner:region"         content="California"> 
  <meta property="your-og-app:owner:postal_code"    content="94304"> 
  <meta property="your-og-app:owner:country_name"   content="United States"> 
  <meta property="your-og-app:owner:email"          content="nospam@fb.com"> 
  <meta property="your-og-app:owner:phone_number"   content="111-111-1111"> 
  <meta property="your-og-app:owner:fax_number"     content="111-111-1111"> 
  <meta property="your-og-app:owner:website"    
        content="http://www.facebook.com">
</head>
<body>
    <!--a wonderful web page of Sample Restaurant -->
</body>
</html>
```

For more information You should read the [open graph protocal](http://ogp.me/).

Comment: thanks!! I am out now but will test this when I get back. Would the custom properties (e.g. all the owner content in your complex object type) show up in an action post of the restaurant?

Comment: works! thanks! Is it possible to include a video (say youtube) instead of the image in the action post, but clicking on the post still take the user my webpage instead of only playing back the video?